# Matching a single element to an element dictionary key/value pair where the values are lists themselves

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

I've made a dictionary where the keys are the lower case letters of the English alphabet and each key's corresponding value is a list of words that start with that letter. The lists contain words that are both upper and lowercase.

so for example: myDict= {'a':['Apple','all','always','allow','Adam',....], 'b': ['base','Bill','ball',....],...

I'm then reading from a separate text file and checking if each word in the text file exists in my dictionary and then if not store that word into another list.

What I'm doing now is checking if the first letter of my word (lowercased) that I'm comparing is a key in my dictionary. Then I wanted to check for the whole word in that key's value list.

I know I could check for all values in my dictionary but I don't really understand what the point of having a dictionary is If I check all values in my dictionary for that word.

What I want to know is whats the best/most efficient way of handling cases like this?

I'm pretty new to python so excuse me If I'm completely missing something. I feel like using a dictionary and checking all values is no different than using a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's good practice to post your actual code, not a description of what your code looks like.

```
myDict= {'a':['Apple','all','always','allow','Adam',....], 'b': ['base','Bill','ball',....]
```

I don't know if this is the **best** way, but this is a way:

```
for word in example_file:
    first_letter = word[0].lower()
    if first_letter in myDict and word in myDict[first_letter]:
        print("{} found in myDict!".format(word))
```

Avoiding case-sensitivity:

```
for word in example_file:
    first_letter = word[0].lower()
    if first_letter in myDict and word.lower() in [x.lower() for x in myDict[first_letter]:
        print("{} found in myDict!".format(word))
```

Depends on what kind of search you're after

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the super fast response.  My goal was to look for words not found in my dictionary, but Next time I will add the code but it was basically just a line opening a file and the making a list from the words of the file. My new problem now is how to handle cases where the first letter is a special character or a number. I think I'm going to have to play around with how to manipulate the strings to remove things like periods at the end of a word or numbers or special characters. Also PS My account is so new that it won't show my upvote of your answer.